# cell style through code WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to set the cell style in code but have been unable to do so:

xaml:

```
CellStyle="{StaticResource DefaultCell}"
```

Which works perfect.

In the code behind I have tired a few variations of:

```
datagrid.CellStyle = Resources["DefaultCell"] as Style;
datagrid.CellStyle = (Style)FindResource("DefaultCell");
```

but have been unable to get this to work, any ideas?

Comment: Does the `Style` your looking for get returned by the call to `FindResource`?

Comment: no i don't think so - have been unable to find out how to get a static resource like you are able to in xaml.

Comment: @user101010101 Try 'harcoding' it in XAMl and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the style at hand, it makes sense to define it also at in code (new style, new setter, ...) it seems to me you question is rather : "how to get resources from code behind ?".

Comment: Yes Vincent maybe that would be a better way of saying my problem - any ideas?

Comment: look in this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245172/tryfindresource-is-not-able-to-find-the-resource      to the ChaosMaker reply, it is a good start

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried method `FindResource("DefaultCell")` ?

Comment: In which file are you writing this code? code behind? and is this resource declared in Window.Resources?

Comment: In the code behind, I can get the cell resource to work in xaml fine, but I need to be able to do this same in the code behind, I am working from the class attached to the xaml.

Comment: I have declared it like this ` <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="DefaultCell" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}"/>
    </Window.Resources>`

Comment: can you show me the casting for it in terms of - datagrid.CellStyle =

Comment: dg.CellStyle =(Style) FindResource("DefaultCell");

Answer (score 0):

Do you set style type?

```
<Style TargetType="local:DataGridCell">
...
</Style>
```

Comment: yes in the xaml i set:      <Style
                x:Key="DefaultCell"
                TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">

Comment: Try to add your resource in App.xaml resources section, may be problems in scope